# Why $\min_{a\in \Bbb C}\max \{|1-ax|,|1-ay|\}$ with given $x,y\in \Bbb C$ is attained at $a=\frac{2}{x+y}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider complex numbers. Given $x,y \in \Bbb C$, how can we see the following

> $\min_{a\in \Bbb C}\max \{|1-ax|,|1-ay|\}$

is attained when $a=\frac{2}{x+y}$? The absolute value is the modulus of complex numbers.

Many thanks!

---

The previous post is not good (too many changes in the question), and there was no answer, so I open a new one.

Comment: [Previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462863/help-explain-an-equality-why-max-i-1-alpha-lambda-i-max-1-alpha-l) linked here for context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The estimate for the smallest possible value for the $\max$ is a bit off.

OK, first of all we know that $x$ and $y$ are real. That's not a big omission.

We have 
$$x(1-a y) - y(1-a x) = x-y$$

Conversely, if $x$, $y$ are both non-zero, any solution of 
$$x u - y v = x-y$$ is of form $u = 1-a y$, $v = 1- a x$ for some $a$. 
From the equality above for $u$, $v$ we get
$$(|x| + |y|)\max (|u|,|v|) \ge |xu| +|yv|\ge |xu-yv|=|x-y||$$ so
$$\max(|u|, |v|) \ge \frac{|x-y|}{|x|+ |y|}$$
This is the best that can be said, that is: this value can be achieved.

However, for $a= \frac{2}{x+y}$ we get both $(1-ax) = \frac{y-x}{x+y}$ and $1-a y = \frac{x-y}{x+y}$ so both absolute values are $\frac{|x-y|}{|x+y|}$. That is not always the smallest possible value for the $\max$. Example: Take $x$, $y$ real of opposite sign. For $a=0$ we get both values $=1$, the smallest possible value. Note that $\frac{|x-y|}{|x+y|}$ is $>1$ in this case.

Conclusion: the paper is a bit off, not too much. It's OK if $x$, $y$ are real of same sign ( or complex of same argument).

Comment: Thanks! I am following the steps until $(|x| + |y|)\max (|u|,|v|) \ge |x-y|$. How do we arrive at this from the previous step? I don't quite get it "from the equality for $u,v$".

Comment: @River: Added some details